# How do you work in team?

Tags: zend-framework, cakephp

I always designed/developed/released a software or web project myself/independent activity using java/vb.net and php (intermediate level of experience). But recently i have to work in a company with team of **5+ using Zend or Cakephp.**

Q. My question is how do you  work  using php frameworks in team and all those SVN staffs?
10 ppls will make one class? or one module? or one front page? How is it made or gets implemented, in most cases? Can someone explain in details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice would be to map work/resources to *features*, not to implementation. There are a lot of reasons for this, but here are the ones I think are key:

1. You'll communicate better with business types because your organization and work maps to their functionality.
2. Many, and perhaps most, technical components will play some role in multiple features. It's much easier, IMO, to have many hands operating on one source file than to have one hand operating across multiple business functions/features. A good SCM will help with problems arising from the former.

This doesn't eliminate, negate or trivialize the need for good internal communication, though. Tech teams *must* communicate effectively where cross-cutting concerns are identified.

Comment: I'd also be more inclined to get certain people working on an MVC stack, with perhaps the front-end guy doing the views, and layouts